# TreeView vertical scrollbar does not expand to the last node, last node is hidden?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, controls, scrollbar

I am experiencing an odd behaviour from a TreeView control.

[image]

As you can see, the last node in the treeview is somehow hidden (although I can select it with keyboard up/down arrow keys) and the scroll bar does not expand to it. In the picture the blue line you see is the selected node that is hidden but luckily still a bit of highlight is visible!

Even when I press pagedown or END keys, I cannot select the last node!

I tried to change height of the treeview control to match the height of nodes but still no success! My treeview is inside a 'panel'. could it be the problem?

**UPDATE**
I am not doing something extraordinary. I just populate with a loop over a List<> (using suspend and resume before and after loop) then the treeview will be populated normally.

```
public class MyNode
{
public string Name {get;set;}
public string Result {get;set;} 
}
//suspending code here (dont have access to paste it here)
    foreach(MyNode node in myNodeList)
    {
    TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
    tn.Text = node.Name;
    tn.Name = node.Result;
    treeView.Nodes.Add(tn);
    }
////unsuspending code here (dont have access to paste it here)
```

Later I allow user to press a button to highlight the nodes that have result set to 'fail':

```
foreach(TreeNode node in treeView.Nodes)
{
if (node.Name.ToString() == "fail") node.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

After this, the last node in the treeview is going hidden!!!

**FIX**
I used BeginUpdate() and EndUpdate() methods and the problem is gone!!!

Comment: can you show designer file code how control is initialized? At least we could reproduce that behavior and check whats wrong.

Comment: It would be best if you post your solution as an accepted answer, not in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that I have to user `treeView.BeginUpdate()` and `treeView.EndUpdate()`  methods before and after populating the tree view and also making any changes to its nodes.

Answer (score 4):

You should use SuspendLayout() and ResumeLayout() before and after adding the nodes.
This will solve the problem.

You may also want to use BeginUpdate() before SuspendLayout() and EndUpdate() after ResumeLayout().

Edit: This is a known issue in .Net 2.0. 
Disabling visual styles will help.
If you don't want to disable visual styles you could add an empty node to the end of the tree (when there are more than fit in the visible treeview control).
See the issue at MS: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94021/treeview-does-not-display-the-last-node

Comment: @Sean87 Try disabling visual styles.

Comment: Hmm I dont know who negative voted your answer, but it would be better if he could add a comment or answer atleast! c'mon people stop downvoting and running away.

Comment: No...I think this is a very serious case!!

Comment: hmm I am using .Net 4, can it be the same case?!

Comment: Possibly. Did you try disabling visual styles?

Comment: luckily the problem is solved now, I had to use BeginUpdate and EndUpdate methods befor and after populating and changing color of the nodes!

Comment: The URL in the answer is broken